# Antispam filter, list problems

Tags: python, list, label, filtering, bayesian

Goodmorning, I need a help.. I'm trying to program a spam filter for my graduation thesis.. I have countered the frequences of the words of the emails in a list.. Now i should extract the features from the emails and pair them with the email class label (“spam” or “ham”). But there is no output, i need an other solution to class this labels with the frequences of the words..I post you only the last part of the code with frequences and my try of lebeling the frequences. In the text time i'm going to use NaivebayesianFilter...Sorry for my bad english.. Thanks in advance!

```html
ps = PorterStemmer()
i = 0
while i < 5174:
    emails[i]=[[ps.stem(parola) for parola in sentence.split(" ")] for sentence in emails[i]]
    i=i+1


print(emails[1])
i = 0
while i < 5174:
    frequenzeparole[i]= Counter(elem[0] for elem in emails[i])
    i=i+1

i = 0
while i < 5174:
    all_features =[ (frequenzaparole[i], spam) for (frequenzaparole[i], spam) in emails[i]]
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, all_features doesn't output because it's wrong..I need an other solution to extract the features from the emails and pair them with the email class label (“spam” or “ham”)..